# SSIS script task validation error upon

Tags: sql-server, script-task, ssis

I am getting the following error in SSIS Script task (SSIS 2015)

> Adding Data to var:Error: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.

Did some online research and made sure to do the following based on my search results:

1. Delay Validation has been set to true
2. Build has been set to x86
3. We need this script to run on 32 bit compiler

Fails when executed as a deployed package on SQLServer (SSMS) Integration Services Catalogs (not as a job)

Comment: I take it, when you go into the script task, it does build correctly?

Comment: correct, everything works perfection when i build locally

Comment: Is the SSIS package set as the same SQL server version as the server it is running on?

Comment: SSIS: 2015, SQLServer: 2014

Comment: So if this runs fine locally, how does it fail? When run as a job? Please add more detail

Comment: No, not the VS version.  What SQL server version is the SSIS built as?  They have to match.  Previous to VS 2015, it was hard-wired and you have to use the corresponding version of VS that matched your SQL Server.  Starting in VS2015 you can select it.  Goto the project properties > Configuration properties > General.  make sure you are targeting SQL Server 2014

Comment: The SSIS is build with SQLServer version is 2012, but the SQLServer itself is 2014

Comment: Sorry, I should say that the SSIS build target version is 2012.  SQLServer version is 2014.  However, when i go to services.msc, I see that MsDtsServer110 is running, which indicates the SQL Server Integration Services version is 2012